# Construct $A_\infty$ bimodules maps from dg-maps

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras, a-infinity-algebras

Let $ A $ be a dg-algebra. Let $U,V,W$ and $Z$ be dg-bimodules over $A$-$A$. Suppose I have cofibrant replacements $\pi_U : Up \rightarrow U$ (as right dg-module) and $\pi_W : pW \rightarrow W$ (as left dg-module). I can use $\pi_U$ to endow $Up$ with an $A_\infty$-bimodule structure over $A$-$A$, so that $\pi_U$ becomes an $A_\infty$ quasi-isomorphism, and similarly for $pW$.  Also suppose $\pi_U \otimes 1 : Up \otimes_A V \xrightarrow{\simeq} U \otimes_A V$ is a quasi-isomorphism, and so is $1 \otimes \pi_W$. Thus I have $A_\infty$-bimodule maps $(\pi_U \otimes 1)^{-1}$ and $(1 \otimes \pi_V)^{-1}$ that are their quasi-inverses.

Suppose I have a map $f : Z \rightarrow Up \otimes_A V \otimes_A pW$ of complexes of graded vector spaces. If the composition $(\pi_U \otimes 1) \circ f : Z \rightarrow U \otimes_A V \otimes_A pW$ is a map of left dg-modules, then I can define a map $$f' := (\pi_U \otimes 1)^{-1} \circ ((\pi_U \otimes 1) \circ f) : Z \rightarrow Up \otimes_A V \otimes_A pW$$ of left $A_\infty$-modules, whose degree zero part is $f$. 
Now suppose we also have that $(1\otimes \pi_W) \circ f' : Z \rightarrow Up \otimes V \otimes W$ is a map of right dg-modules. Then, I can define $$f'' := (1 \otimes \pi_W)^{-1} \circ ((1\otimes \pi_W) \circ f') : Z \rightarrow Up \otimes_A V \otimes_A pW.$$
If I understand this correctly, it should be both a map of left $A_\infty$-modules, and of right $A_\infty$-modules. However, this does not mean it is a map of $A_\infty$-bimodules, since I could need higher maps mixing both the left and the right action. 
However, if I assume that $Z$ and $Up \otimes_A V \otimes W$ are concentrated only in homological degree 0 and 1, then all such higher maps must vanish. Thus, $f''$ should be a map of $A_\infty$-bimodules. Does that seem right ? And are there any other criterions that would allow me to conclude in the case where I don't have this degree hypothesis ?

More generally, I'm interested in finding ways to build maps of $A_\infty$-bimodules from $Z$ to $Up \otimes_A V \otimes pW$, from a map of graded complexes that gives maps of left or right dg-modules after composition with quasi-isomorphisms.